# Search in ListView with Kotlin

Tags: android, listview, kotlin, adapter

So I've read alot of guides\questions about it but I'm still confused. I've got an array of platforminfo objects which contains address, lat, lng and id. My listview only shows address. I also have an edittext in which I want to type needed adress. I cant understand how to use custom adapter, what should I implement, `BaseAdapter` or `Filterable` and how to use it in my specific case.

My adapter:

```
class PlatformAdapter(ctx: Context) : ArrayAdapter<PlatformInfo>(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ArrayOfPlatforms), Filterable{
override fun getView(position: Int, ConvertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
    val platform: PlatformInfo? = getItem(position)
    val convertView: View? =
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null)
    convertView!!.findViewById<TextView>(android.R.id.text1).text = platform!!.Address
    return convertView
}
}
```